# Handling JQuery/CSS errors in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, width

I've got some code to maximize a video panel on page load / resize.  I'm using JQuery 1.4.4 and everything is working great in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.  Following some examples from some other posts, I adjust the video panel size based on the rendered size and styling of the other elements on the screen.

```
function maximizeVideo(){
  var play_height = $(window).height()-42;
  var play_width = $PLAY.width() - $NAV.width();

  play_width -= parseInt($NAV.css("paddingLeft"), 10) + parseInt($NAV.css("paddingRight"), 10); 
  play_width -= parseInt($NAV.css("marginLeft"), 10) + parseInt($NAV.css("marginRight"), 10); 
  play_width -= parseInt($NAV.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt($NAV.css("borderRightWidth"), 10); 

  $NAV.css('height',play_height-16+"px");
  $VIDEO_PANEL.resize(play_width, play_height);
}
```

In IE the css accessor sometimes returns NaN.  Is there a better way to account for the rendered width of the other element?
If not, what's the best way to trap these errors?

Thanks!

Comment: $ALL_CAPS signifies a jQuery object defined outside this function.  The resize(w,h) function has internal logic to handle resizing the video div and placing video control elements, history, etc.  AFAIK a CSS-only solution is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation, I think you should be looking at the [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) function instead of `width`. Using `outerWidth(true)`, we can obtain the width of the element including its borders, padding and margin. Therefore you can replace this line:

```
var play_width = $PLAY.width() - $NAV.width();
```

with this:

```
var play_width = $PLAY.width() - $NAV.outerWidth(true);
```

And thus eliminating the next three lines of calculations altogether.

---

Additionally, the `height` and `width` functions are not just getters, but also setters, so this line:

```
$NAV.css('height',play_height-16+"px");
```

can be rewritten as

```
$NAV.height(play_height - 16);
```